# How does Reflection/Mirroring padding work? In numpy or in general?

Tags: numpy, padding

I am running the following against a vector say [1,2,3]. The first 2 of them I can explain. Each additional padded coordinate is mirrored around the last element (3). However after that I can't.

There's definitely a cycle of 4 here which means a `mod of 2*(len(a) -1)`.

I'd appreciate if someone broke this down. This example is for end reflection. If the begin reflection is any different I'd love to hear about that too:

```
>>> a
array([1., 2., 3.])
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,1)), 'reflect')
array([1., 2., 3., 2.])
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,2)), 'reflect')
array([1., 2., 3., 2., 1.])
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,3)), 'reflect')
array([1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 2.])
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,4)), 'reflect')
array([1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 2., 3.])
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,5)), 'reflect')
array([1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 2., 3., 2.])
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,6)), 'reflect')
array([1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 2., 3., 2., 1.])
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,7)), 'reflect')
array([1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 2.])
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,8)), 'reflect')
array([1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 2., 3.])
>>> np.pad(a, ((0,9)), 'reflect')
array([1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 2., 3., 2., 1., 2., 3., 2.])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine stepping through the original array, and every time you hit a boundary you go the other direction.

When you progress to the right and get to the end, you reflect and start iterating back to the beginning. When you progress to the left and get to the beginning, you reflect and start iterating back to the end.

It might help to visualize the sequence this way, as a series of reflections:

```
[1, 2, 3]

 1
    2
       3
    2
 1
    2
       3
    2
 1
    2
       3
    2
 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice visualization